# Confusion on the definition of an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(y(t))=y\circ y(t),$$
Whats wrong with considering this as an ordinary differential equation (ODE) under the specifications $t,y \in \Bbb R$, as we treat $$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y),$$ as the general form of a first order ODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **ordinary** differential equation is an equation for function value and derivatives at one single point $x$. (For a solution this equation is then expected to hold at all points $x$ of an open interval.)

Your equation $y'(x)=y(y(x))$ evaluates the function $y$ at two points $x$ and $y(x)$ that usually are not the same. The catch-all name for this situation is **functional** differential equation. In most cases, there is no general solution theory. This is a little better for **delay**-differential equation where function values and derivatives at multiple points with a fixed distance $x,x-d_1,...x-d_m$ are connected in one equation.

Comment: Sir, So you are telling that $y'(t)=y(t^2)$ is also in that situation, right?

Comment: Yes. It is somewhat related to DDE as $\ln(\ln(t^2))=\ln(\ln(t))+\ln(2)$.